# Having different database sorting order (default_scope) for two different views

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

In my model (pins.rb), I have two sorting orders:

```
default_scope order: 'pins.featured DESC' #for adding featured posts to the top of a list
default_scope order: 'pins.created_at DESC' #for adding the remaining posts beneath the featured posts
```

This sorting order (above) is how I want my 'pins view' (index.html.erb) to look. Which is just a list of ALL user posts.

In my 'users view' (show.html.erb) I am using the same model (pins.rb) to list only current_user pins. HOWEVER, I want to sorting order to ignore the "featured" default scope and only use the second scope:

```
default_scope order: 'pins.created_at DESC'
```

How can I accomplish this? I tried doing something like this:

```
default_scope order: 'pins.featured DESC', only: :index
default_scope order: 'pins.created_at DESC'
```

But that didn't fly...

**UPDATE**

I updated my model to define a scope:

```
scope :featy,  order: 'pins.featured DESC'
default_scope order: 'pins.created_at DESC'
```

And updated my pins view to:

```
<%= render @pins.featy %>
```

However, now when I open my pins view, I get the error:

```
undefined method `featy' for #<Array:0x00000100ddbc78>
```

Comment: Why not have a default scope and another explicit scope?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on using an explicit scope? I am new to this and haven't heard of that yet. So are you saying I can have an explicit scope for a certain view or controller? @muistooshort

Comment: [Define a scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) and then call it when you don't want to use the default scope. A scope is really just a way to define to a class method.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks, I took your suggestion, however now I'm getting an error (see my update)

Comment: Can you post some of your code?  More specifically the association definitions on user and pin.  And then also your Users Show Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into doing something like the following:

**Pins.rb**:

This will result in having the featured at the top of the list, with a secondary sort of them sorted by when they were created.  *(Note two methods of sorting by boolean)*

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope  order: 'created_at DESC'
  # Method 1      
  scope :featy,  order('featured DESC, created_at DESC')
  # Method 2
  # scope :featy,  order('(case when featured then 1 else 0 end) DESC, created_at DESC')
end
```

**User.rb**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pins
end
```

**UsersController.rb**:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # Pins are accessed via: @user.pins
    # These should be sorted by `created_at DESC` as that is the default_scope
  end
end
```

**users/show.html.erb**:
*This is all of the users pins sorted by `created_at desc`*

```
<%= @user.pins %>
```

**PinsController.rb**:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Pins sorted by created_at: @pins = Pin.all
    # Pins sorted by created_at with all featured on top: 
    @pins = Pin.featy
  end
end
```

**pins/index.html.erb:**
*This is all pins sorted by `created_at desc` with all featured on top*

```
<%= @pins %>
```

Comment: This assumes he's calling `.all` AND he's not using Rails 4.

Comment: Well all is really just an example i suppose, Its hard to see without more code.

Comment: Ah, but actually, he can't be using Rails 4 because he's allowed to create scopes that aren't wrapped in `lambda`s. He's probably calling `.all` then, but not necessarily.

Comment: @MichaelLynch You are right I am calling .all (see update) So, your solution should work? I can give it a try.

Comment: If I already have: `has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy` in my User.rb, do I still need to include: `has_many :recent_pins, order: 'created_at DESC', class_name: "Pins", source: :pins` ?

Comment: @MichaelLynch I am still having trouble. No errors, but the sorting is not working the way I want. I pasted ALL my model and controller code for you to have a look if you can. Look above, under UPDATE 2.

Comment: Also, I commented out the has_many :featured_pins because there is not a separate table for featured pins. Only one pins table with a Boolean column which denotes if a pin is "featured" or not.

Comment: Ah ~ Was unaware of the boolean, however the rest remains the same.  The `has_many :featured_pins` doesn't reference a `featured_pin` table, if you look it specifies the class as 'Pin'.  The name of your association does *not* have to match anything in particular.

Comment: However looking at your question again, you dont even care about a users featured pins.  I just reupdated my answer with a few changes.

Comment: Ok. The changes you made make sense. It's still not sorting though and I think I know why. Ruby does not sort Boolean (t/f) values. Is there a way I can trick it so that all of the featured (true) values are first?

Comment: Updated :D  [Didn't even think about the order on boolean field >.<, but the above code *should* work]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40685/discussion-between-juniper747-and-michael-lynch)

Comment: Sorry missed your chat invite thing last night.  I see you marked it as correct, did you get it working?

Comment: No... still not working. I marked it correct because in theory everything looks ok. For some reason it doesn't like the boolean stuff and is defaulting to either the default_scope or if I comment out the default scope, it defaults to the created_at DESC' of the :featy scope.

Comment: I believe my sort order is correct, but have you tried switching the position of the `created_at desc` and `(case...) desc` inside the :featy scope? 0.o

Comment: I just tested the sorting of booleans and the sort order and it appears that with rails you **can** sort by boolean, i had no issues doing so.  Also the first item in the order by is given the most priority.  (clarified answer with findings)

Comment: So- it now works! But I had to remove default_scope [apparently it is evil](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil) And then I just created a separate scope: `scope :created_at_order, order('created_at DESC')`

Answer (score 1):

In Active Record, queries against the database aren't executed until needed. When you call a scope on a model (ex. `Pins.featy`), you haven't actually fetched data from the DB yet. This allows you to chain more scopes (ex. `Pins.featy.wheaty`).

Most likely, you're doing something to `@pins` to coerce it into fetching from the DB. Can you share what you're doing in your controller?